# ExoPlayer, MediaSource created Video Player not Playing the video extracted from a URL

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exoplayer, media-source

I'm trying to create an `ExoPlayer` Video Player using the `MediaSource`. I have created a simple video player to play an `.mp4` video file extracted from a online server. My created app opens normally and I am not getting any error but my video player is not playing the video. Please Help me.

My `MainActivity.java` code:

```
package com.example.amans.my_video_player;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    boolean shouldAutoPlay = true;
    DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Application Name"), bandwidthMeter);

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));

        player.prepare(mediaSource);
    }
}
```

My `activity_main.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
      android:id="@+id/player_view"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:focusable="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My `build.gradle` added dependency:

```
dependencies
{
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.8.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.1'
}
```

The Problem I'm getting:

```
`Dependency`:
```

[image]

```
`MainActivity.java`:
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change only mediasource line to this, it's tested.

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "Application Name"), defaultBandwidthMeter);

MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
```

Comment: I'm getting error for the `context` variable and `ExtractorMediaSource.Factory`. Can you tell me how to declare the `context` variable and for `Factory` it says `cannot resolve symbol Factory`.

Comment: you can replace context to getContext() or this

Comment: remove ur all exoplayer implementation and replace with 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1' newer version library

Comment: I have tried your method but this time getting two errors which idk how to fix. I have uploaded my current codes and the pictures of the two error ABOVE. Help me please

Comment: SimpleExoPlayerView is deprecated in newer version of exoplayer so you have to use PlayerView.

Comment: Add design library implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.6.0' and then also you are getting problem then use newer version of appcompat implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'.

Comment: Yes. It finally works. Thanks for all your help. Thank You

Comment: I have stored a video file in the `raw` folder in `res` called `test.mp4`. I'm trying to play that video rather than using the URL video. I'm replacing the URL with the `uri` variable but it does not work. Can you help me? `String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test;`

Comment: you can use **RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.filename);** it returns Uri.